# Is it possible to run a Python web scraper via AWS SWF and Lambda Function?

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-swf

I made a Python web scraper for downloading more than 4PB to 8PB data from the web. I have to run More than 1k + spider per sec for downloading data from 12  websites. If I use ec2 instance it will be very costally. Someone told me to use SWF And lambda. But I didn't find anything on the web About web scraper with SWF.

Is it possible to run this spider via Amazon Simple Workflow Service OR AWS Lambda?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you could use lambda if your scraper needs to download a high amount of data.

Take a look at [AWS Lambda Limits](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/limits.html)

How about [EC2 Spot Instances](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-spot-instances.html)? You can still use ec2 instances with an effective cost.